# I can resolve "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'", but it returns just days later. Why is that?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I am constantly getting the following error when attempting to debug my .NET Core 3.0 project in Visual Studio 2019:

> Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'

I am able to resolve this issue after going through the following list:

- Delete `applicationhost.config`
- Delete the entire `/Documents/IISExpress` folder
- Reinstall VIsual Studio
- Reinstall IIS

After some combination of these (that seems to vary from day to day), the project builds and all is well. But a few days later (in some cases the very next day), the issue is back, and I have to repeat these steps all over again. You can imagine how frustrating this becomes.

Does anyone know why this issue continues to happen? Is it something I'm unknowingly causing?

Comment: This is probably because the port is being used. Try changing the port in the `App URL` field  in `Project Properties` > `Debug`, delete the `.vs` hidden folder and try again (may require you to close Visual Studio and/or restart windows).

Comment: You didn't resolve the actual issue, so it can come back anytime. https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html Learn what actually bothers you, and next time you can easily fix it.

Comment: @LexLi "Learn what actually bothers you and next time you can easily fix it". Well yes, that's my intention, and exactly why I'm asking this question. Up until now I have not seen the link you've shared. Perhaps you could make your comment an answer? Regardless, thanks for the help. I'll read through this now.